# How many fourth powers are below $n^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given $n^2$, how many fourth powers $(x^4)$ are between 0 and $n^2$?

$n,x\in \mathbb{Z}$

Does this just reduce down to how many squares are below $n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does: assuming that $x$ is a non-negative integer, $0\le x^4\le n^2$ if and only if $0\le x^2\le n$. You can express the number of squares exactly using the floor (greatest integer) function; I’ve left the answer spoiler-protected below.

> $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor+1$, where the $+1$ accounts for $0^2$.

Comment: Those were just the inequalities I was looking for! Thanks! Also, how did you do the spoiler-protection? I can't seem to read the LaTex command off of it...

Comment: @zerosofthezeta: You’re welcome! The spoiler-protection is produced by `>!`.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many as there are squares between $0$ and $n$, so the answer is $\sqrt n$, with up or downrounding depending on whether you count $0$ and $n$ itself (if it is square)

Comment: So it does reduce down to how many squares are below $n$. Thanks!